# How to create playlist for all files in folder?

Tags: applications, media-files

I want to use Zombies, Run! and therefore need music that is organized in a playlist. I usually play by album or folder so I never needed to do this before.

What I want to do is copying a folder with the music to the phone (using ftp) and then create a playlist containing all of these files (without having to choose them manually). It would also be okay for me if the app on Android only converts a playlist in `.m3u` or `.pls` format (created on my computer) to a playlist in Android's playlist set.

For now I only found applications that create `.m3u` files (which are not useful for me) or crash upon start.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it's in the top results for "Android create playlist from a folder" so I thought I'd add this:

Playlist Creator 2: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ksdeveloper.playlistcreator.v2

(From what I read, the not so good rating comes from the inhability of the developer to explain how it works, but it's really simple)

1. Download and open the app. (Duh)
2. Top right> Use file explorer.
3. Navigate to the desired folder and long press it.
4. Pick "Add whole folder as playlist".
5. Press the top right icon to open the playlist, name it, Create Playlist.

And voilà, you'll see the playlist in the Google music app and any common music player.

Comment: Doesn't support nested folders :(

Answer (score 0):

[My Music Playlist Creator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matt.mym3ucreator&hl=en_IN) is a good one. It supports nested folders as well. Create an m3u file using this app. Then the m3u file can be imported using [FX File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx&hl=en_IN) app.

Also, check out my related blog: [Creating an offline music playlist on Android](https://nagabhushansn95.wordpress.com/2020/01/25/creating-an-offline-music-playlist-on-android/)